# Ubuntu 17.04 doesn't start

Tags: boot, 17.04

Out of nowhere (i.e, it was working fine last time I used it and shut it down) the computer wont start.

It apparently tries to boot, but it remains stuck on a black screen and 2 lines:

```
/dev/sda4 recovering journal
/dev/sda4: clean, xxxx/xxxxx files xxxx/xxxxx blocks (x are numbers, obviously)
```

I left it overnight, and it has been the same for the last 10+ hours. No progress in the numbers either, it is just stuck and useless.

Is there a way to fix this without a fresh reinstall?

Computer is a a Macbook pro 2011, running Ubuntu Gnome 17.04

Comment: That message isn't supposed to progress and the reason you're seeing it is because the graphics driver failed to load somehow.

Comment: That put me on the right track. Reinstalled graphic drivers and lightdm and now is back to normal. Thanks!